# C - converting char* to unsigned char array

Tags: c, arrays, char, type-conversion

I'm trying hard to convert `char *macAddress` into `unsigned char mac[6]` but without success so far. My input string looks like "00:10:6f:16:01:b3" and I want to devide it into mac[0] = 0x00, mac[1] = 0x10, etc..

I've tried to use `memcpy` like:

```
memcpy(&mac, (unsigned char)macAddress, sizeof mac);
```

or same another ways like `mac = (unsigned char *)macAddress` and so on but nothing worked for me well.
Is there any correct way how to convert it without any precision loss?

Comment: `(unsigned char)macAddress`?? What makes you think you need or should cast a pointer to an `unsigned char`??

Comment: `memcpy` is a C function. Where is you r[mcve] and which language do you use? Remove the tag for the unrelated language.

Comment: What is in macAddress?  Is it a string with colons like "00:10:6f:16:01:b3"?

Comment: Tell us what you're trying to do, not just what types the input and output have.

Comment: Four steps: 1) describe the structure of the data in your input; 2) describe the structure of the desired result; 3) describe the rule for transforming the data in your input into the desired result; 4) write the code.

Comment: sorry guys, my input looks exactly like "00:10:6f:16:01:b3" and I want to devide it into mac[0] = 0x00, mac[1] = 0x10, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to convert hexadecimal digits (i.e. the string "00") of the mac address to byte values (i.e. the value 0). The `memcpy` instead copies the value of the string digits (i.e. '0' is 48 or 0x30).

You can use `sscanf` for the correct conversion.

At least on Linux, you can also use the function `ether_aton`. See the man page.